# Magento 1.7 - Blank page on login and checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, php, controllers

I'm having some trouble with the login page and the checkout page. Here is the debug message whenever i try to login (just show a blank page):

Notice: Undefined variable: message  in /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php on line 182

0 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php(182): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/home/235880.cl...', 182, Array)

1 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Customer_AccountController->loginPostAction()

2 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('loginPost')

3 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

4 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

5 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/app/Mage.php(687): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

6 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/index.php(114): Mage::run('', 'store')

7 {main}

And when i try to do a checkout (One step checkout module), throw this error:

Validate class not found from basename 'EmailAddress'

0 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php(811): Zend_Validate::is('lfsky.pedro@gma...', 
'EmailAddress')
1 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Controller/Action.php(45): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->validate()

2 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/app/code/community/Inovarti/Onestepcheckout/controllers/IndexController.php(16): Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action->_preDispatchValidateCustomer()

3 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(408): Inovarti_Onestepcheckout_IndexController->preDispatch()

4 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')

5 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))

6 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()

7 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/app/Mage.php(687): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

8 /home/235880.cloudwaysapps.com/txagccwhxs/public_html/index.php(114): Mage::run('', 'store')

9 {main}

I really don't know what do to. What do you think?